# Sorting a list of tuples by 2nd item not working in python

Tags: python, list, sorting, lambda

I am trying to sort a list of tuples by their 2nd element. Each tuple in the list consists of a tuple and an integer.

```
l = [((1, 0, 1), 0), ((1, 0, 6), -1), ((1, 0, 8), -1), ((1, 0, 11), 0), ((1, 0, 14), 0), ((1, 0, 15), 0), ((1, 0, 17), -5), ((1, 0, 20), -3),
     ((1, 0, 22), 0), ((1, 0, 24), 0)]

sorted(l, key = lambda x:x[1])

print(l)

sorted(l, key = lambda x:x[0])

print(l)  # same output
```

The first `sorted()` statement should sort the list according to the 2nd elements of the tuples i.e. 0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, -5, -3, 0, 0 and should return a list like this or something similar where the 2nd elements of the tuples are in nondecreasing order:

```
[((1, 0, 17), -5), ((1, 0, 20), -3), ((1, 0, 6), -1), ((1, 0, 8), -1), ((1, 0, 1), 0), ((1, 0, 11), 0), ((1, 0, 14), 0), ((1, 0, 15), 0), 
         ((1, 0, 22), 0), ((1, 0, 24), 0)]
```

But the two `print` statements are printing the same and keeping the original list unchanged. Why? And how to sort the list of tuples by their 2nd element? I even tried `key=itemgetter(1)`, but the result remains the same.

Comment: sorted() returns a new list. Use list.sort() instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sorted` **returns** a sorted version of the list you hand over.

The list itself is unmodified. You're always printing the unsorted list. Try:

```
sorted_list_1 = sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[0])
sorted_list_2 = sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[2])
print (sorted_list1, sorted_list2)
```